# Copy a row from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with a button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has a "customer details" section, and the user enters their information and is able to clear it with a button etc. The only problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to save that information, ie, copy the whole row into sheet2, primarily because the row it copies from uses =cell to get the contents from another cell so its all in one row.

How would I go about copying that row, then moving down one? But not copying the formula, I would like the formulas output, I have looked at pastespecial but can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Try recording a macro with the actions you want to perform and see the generated code... it may help you understand how to automate it

Comment: I have recorded a macro of what I want to happen but where I am copying from formula's it says about it being an error because its not in that sheet, for some reason it wont copy the formula's output..

Comment: Paste the code you are having trouble with so someone can see what has been recorded and will be in a better position to assist you.

Comment: @Barranka nice link +1 :)

Comment: @Polinski The macro will give you hints, it won't solve your problem... With that "auto-generated" code you can try to figure out how to do exactly what you need. Use it, and try to write the solution. If you're still facing problems, then edit your question and include the code you've tried. Your question, as it is right now, is unanswerable

Comment: I ended up solving this, I recorded a macro and then kinda understood how it was doing what it was doing and then added a snippet I found online that always went down a row before pasting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Polinski If you've found a solution, I recommend you post it below as an answer (share your knowledge in a Q&A style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I used this:

```
Range("C38:P38").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Which selects the range you want copied in the first line, then copies, goes to sheet 2, pastes it 1 row down every time and back to sheet 1.